# Wordpress theme not compatible with IE8, add custom splash page for IE8?

Tags: php, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

So i've been building this Wordpress for someone, only to find that the theme is not compatible with IE8 once it was 'finished'. Does anyone know how to go about adding a custom splash page to the wordpress? I've tried adding some IE8 custom style sheet through my header.php but that doesn't seem to do the trick. In an ideal situation I would want to load a completely different website on IE8. The theme wasn't built by me and I don't fully understand the structure of it. http://themeforest.net/item/wisey-high-performance-wordpress-theme/14657503

This is the code that I added to header.php

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="  <?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/ie-8-style.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

In my css files there's a css file called ie-8-style.css, what I want to do is to hide the entire content of the website when a user is running IE8 and show a message that the browser is not supported.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="  <?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/ie-8-style.css" />
<![endif]-->

Comment: That is the code I added to header.php!

Comment: In my opinion, we as developers should stop supporting IE8. That might force the last 2,5% still using it to upgrade from an insecure, 7 years old browser.

Comment: I completely agree, that is why i'm trying to build a splash page for IE8 to say that the system does not support the browser. The client i'm working for understands the problem but doesn't want the usability of the website damaged, which is of course the correct way of stopping support for IE8

Comment: What's the HTML generated using your code?  Any chance the problem is the space between `href="` and `<?php`?

Comment: you'll need to provide a bit more detail, if there is a front-page.php or home.php these are the files you need to modify, you can overwrite them with a child theme and use php to check the user agent. However denying access to users will not make you popular (even if a small number), you could just add a message saying ie<9 may not work as expected. see my answer here for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36670235/how-can-i-enqueue-internet-explorer-specific-stylesheets-in-the-wordpress-functi  (as a new user please make sure you know how to upvote / accept answers etc)

Comment: Yes in the future it'll probably support IE8. It's a page.php (the website is online at http://www.helpybrabant.nl) and i'm adding it as HTML code to the PHP files, is that correct?

Comment: its not really a case of correct or not, just if it works well! page.php is kind of a catchall for page posttypes that have no template assigned so it's not going to work in all cases, but if page.php is the frontpage now you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I've added this

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/ie-8-style.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

To my page.php and this

```
function wisey_load_scripts(){
    // Register or enqueue scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap',  get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.0.1' );
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap',  get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.0.1' );
    wp_enqueue_script('plugins-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/plugins.js', array('jquery'), '3.2', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/functions.js', array('jquery'), '3.2', true);
    wp_register_script('Google-map-api',  'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false', array('jquery'), '3.2', false);
    wp_register_script('Google-map',  get_template_directory_uri().'/js/gmap3.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.2', false);

    if(preg_match("/MSIE [23456789].0/",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ){
   wp_enqueue_style('css/ie-8-style.css');
}
```

Is what my functions.php wisey_load_scripts function looks like.

So what it does is check if the browser is IE8 or lower and load a custom stylesheet if it does and the

```
 if(preg_match("/MSIE [23456789].0/",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ){
   wp_enqueue_style('css/ie-8-style.css');
}
```

Part should do the same?

When I load it on IE with emulation and document set to IE8 nothing seems to change while the custom css tells the browser to hide the body element.

```
    /* STYLING FOR IE8 */
body, {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: And when I remove the comment behind body, it works, haha. Thanks!